# Her name is or her name was?

Tags: meaning, past-tense

If someone has passed away do we say "Her name was Jane" or "Her name is Jane"?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage.  Forgive me for asking at a difficult moment, but a little more context would be helpful. Is this an obituary, or a memorial service....?

Comment: Generally speaking, the past tense ("was") is used when discussing traits of a deceased person.  But, as Cascabel suggests, there may be specific contexts where something else is more appropriate.

Comment: @Cascabel I don't think "Her name was Jane" will likely appear in an obituary or memorial service expected to be read or attended by people who knew the deceased. That sentence might be said by some forensic doctor or police officer informing the name of the victim of an accident or crime. I'd say the past would sound more appropriate, as the person known by that name has ceased to exist as such.

Comment: You might avoid the issue by using a statement that would be true for one living or deceased, such as "She was born Jane Doe"

Comment: However, it is perfectly idiomatic to say in response to the question, 'Who is she?', to say 'Her name is Mary Fitzgibbons', if she is a recently deceased corpse. However, 'My grandfather's name was John' if he be dead, would be more idiomatic than 'My grandfather's name is John', which would suggest he is alive.

Comment: Uh… what? No way is that at all, let alone primarily opinion-based.

While she was alive, her name was Jane and at that time it would have been wholly appropriate to say ‘Her name is Jane.’

Since the moment she ceased to be alive, her name 'is' not anything but clearly 'was' Jane

Sorry, Cascabel; Hot Licks but there are not specific contexts where something else is more appropriate. Clearly, Gustavson’s view is a great deal more realistic.
This is borne out by most of the gravestones you have ever read

Answer (score 4):

I've found a multitude of sources, and they all seem to concur that the use of the past tense is preferable when referring to deceased people, even though it's a matter of preference. It's up to you really, but I'd recommend past. A person who no longer exists in consciousness has no possessions, sorry to be blunt about it.

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-correct-verb-tenses-to-use-in-reference-to-dead-people

[Grammar and dead relatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229808/grammar-and-dead-relatives)

[What tense to use for a dead person's permanent contributions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56471/what-tense-to-use-for-a-dead-persons-permanent-contributions)

http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1148807-grammar-english-question-concerning-past-tense-deceased

https://www.englishforums.com/English/ConfusedUsingPastTenseDeadThings-CeasedExist/xcvrm/post.htm

http://fandom-grammar.livejournal.com/75067.html

https://www.yelp.com/topic/burlingame-grammar-question-past-or-present-tense

http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/2106079225

https://www.italki.com/question/101137